# SQL: Can I have fields on Group By clause not appearing on Select clause?

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, select, group-by

I know I can't have fields on `Select` not appearing on `Group By`. But may I go the other way? For example:

```
Select B
From Table
Group By A,B
```

Comment: the reverse is also possible in mysql - since you tagged it. not advised unless you're sure you're getting consistent results - but possible.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/29611/1

Comment: It would faster to test than it was to ask

Comment: @Strawberry: This user does not feel he has to test anything, or even learn basic SQL commands. We're supposed to do all of that, and then just spoonfeed the solutions to him. See [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30147349/sql-can-i-have-a-group-by-clause-after-a-nestled-select?noredirect=1#comment48412847_30147349) from another very similar question that could have been answered by a two-minute test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible.
Example

```
select MAX(salary) max_sal
from Employee
group by Department_id
```